# 'TestCafe Browser Tools' wants to access 'Google Chrome'. Mac security popup issue. Is there a settings in Mac to always allow?

Tags: macos, security, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

On Mac (Mojave 10.14.6) CI machine, any time I upgrade TestCafe to the latest version and run a test job, I get this Mac permission popup (see screenshot). I have to manually log into that machine and click 'Allow' to get rid of this popup for the test job to launch a chrome browser otherwise it fails.

Is there a setting in Mac to make always allow/give access to control?

[image]

UPDATE: I did provide permission to 'TestCafe Browser Tools' in the settings but that doesn't seem to help. (see screenshot

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify with what TestCafe versions this issue occurs? Did you need to give a permission each time for each TestCafe version or only for 1.6.0?

Comment: @DmitryOstashev - I think this used to happen before for previous TestCafe versions but I recently started seeing this frequently when installing TestCafe v1.6.0 and upgrading to v1.6.1. (see new screenshot attached).  This is easy to reproduce.  Just create a new npm project. Add TestCafe as project dependency and try to run a testCafe test script and you should see the permission popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestCafe Browser Tools is a special helper app used by TestCafe 1.6.0 and newer. TestCafe uses it for features that access operating system APIs like taking screenshots, opening, closing and resizing browser windows and so on.

Using a dedicated app for such functionality is necessary for providing a convenient way to obtain the new 'Screen Recording' security permission introduced in macOS 10.15 Catalina, but it also delivers more secure permission management for the older macOS versions as well.

The first drawback of using the TestCafe Browser Tools app is that you have to give permissions to the app when you upgrade to TestCafe 1.6.0 from the older TestCafe versions. Another drawback is that macOS can reset permissions granted to TestCafe and show the permission dialog again if the app's content is changed after an update.

We have to apply hotfixes to TestCafe Browser Tools used in TestCafe 1.6.1 and 1.7.0. It means that permissions can be requested again when you upgrade to these versions.

But TestCafe Browser Tools shipped with TestCafe 1.7.0 can be considered stable and we won't change it frequently in the future TestCafe versions. It means that you will not see additional permission dialogs starting from TestCafe 1.7.0.